# Use affjax http request in an ExceptT context

Tags: ajax, monad-transformers, purescript

most of the IO functions in my program result in this type:

`ExceptT Err (Eff eff) a`

this works well for me and it's quite composable. However, I have some problems now to integrate an AJAX call in one function.

I don't need asynchronous behavior, however to me it looked that Affjax is the most common library to do this. Say for, now I'd like the result to be a String, then I am basically looking for a function with this signature:

`getData :: forall eff. ExceptT Err (Eff (ajax :: AJAX | eff)) String`

Here's how far I got, it stays in the Aff context however:

```
getData :: forall eff.
  ExceptT
    Error
    (Aff ( ajax :: AJAX | eff ))
    String
getData =
  Ajax.get "the/url" # attempt # wrap # map _.response
```

But how do I write this, so that it composes well with the Eff context?

Answer (score 0):

INFO: I'm answering this question in the context of PureScript 0.12 even though the question is using pre 0.12 `Eff` approach.

> I am basically looking for a function with this signature:
>
> ```hs
> getData :: forall eff. ExceptT Err (Eff (ajax :: AJAX | eff)) String
> ```

Currently `purescript-affjax` [calls `XMLHttpRequest.open`](https://github.com/slamdata/purescript-affjax/blob/master/src/Affjax.js#L46) in async mode as it uses `true` value in the second argument (more `XMLHttpRequest` API details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests)).

It is impossible to easily replace "xhr driver" which is run by `affjax` in the current version of this library but there is [ongoing discussion](https://github.com/slamdata/purescript-affjax/issues/101) about making this piece configurable.

In other words if you are using current or previous versions of `affjax` you have no choice and have to run it in `Aff`. If you **really** want to run your ajax call in a synchronous manner you have to probably write your own `FFI` for it or... contribute to the library :-)

> But how do I write this, so that it composes well with the Eff context?

In general there is no way to turn `Aff` into an `Effect` computation. This make sens if you think about `Effect` as an abstraction which models sequence of instruction without notion of "future" or "time". We are just not able to "return" future value right now...

Of course there is `liftEffect` which can turn synchronous computation into `Aff` because we can always take synchronous computation and just run it in the future.

I think that it is quite usual when you are using default `javascript` PureScript backend to turn your whole application into `Aff` and use `launchAff_` in the `main` function.